# Can tmux query physical terminal? (Maybe iTerm2 only)

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I'm trying to detect the presence of `iTerm2` and if I run the following in iTerm2 (`echo -n $'\e[5n'; read -s -t 0.1 line; printf '%q\n' "$line"`) the terminal responds with `$'\033'\[ITERM2\ 3.2.1n$'\033'\[0n`

However, if I am running a tmux session in the terminal, then tmux responds and gives me nothing.

Any idea how I can ask tmux to query the physical terminal to report its status?

#### Footnotes

- Here is a description of `[5n` in the tmux source: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/486ce9b09855ae30a2bf5e576cb6f7ad37792699/tools/ansicode.txt#L577
- This might be iTerm2 only, since I haven't seen a response on any other terminal

Comment: In this case, `echo` echoes to the immediate terminal it's within, which is tmux. tmux would then have to pass the `$'\e[5n'` to the terminal it's contained within (iTerm2), but instead tmux personally responds to the `echo`. I'm not personally sure how to avoid that.

Comment: I just found this [ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213799/can-bash-write-to-its-own-input-stream ] and maybe I can bind a response in tmux have it type the term when it sees the '\e[0n'

Answer (score 1):

According to ft in freenode's #tmux (and as seen in [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/603663/709801)), you can use:

```
'\ePtmux;\e" STUFF_FOR_THE_TERMINAL_HERE "\e\\'
```

So, it would be something like:

```
echo -n $'\ePtmux;\e\e[5n\e\\'
```